# ValueError when read_html using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a web application which is made using flask and I have used pandas to_html() function to export excel as html table in the first place. I have made few changes to the html table using javascript and want to write those changes to the excel also so that they get saved everytime I reload the page.

Now, I am using Pandas read_html() function convert that html table back to excel and complete write operation

```
url = '127.0.0.1:5000/'
data = pd.read_html(url)
data.to_excel(filename,index=False)
```

But it says `ValueError: Table not found`
Can anybody tell whats wrong because my flask application is running when I execute this script.

This is how my index.html looks like

```
<div class=page>
<!-- <h1>Python</h1> -->
{% for table in tables %}
      <h2>{{titles[loop.index]}}</h2>
      {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

and I am using this to render it

```
render_template('index.html',tables=[re.sub(' mytable', '" id="example', data.to_html(classes='mytable'))],
titles = ['Excel Data to Flask'])
```

Comment: please post the html code that you are feeding to `pd.read_html()`

Comment: Check now. As this is what my index.html looks like thats why I am using the localhost as url

Answer (score 0):

You can parse tables to a template using:

*This example is made with pandas, but I hope to help you.*

Having a table like this:

```
ipdst           proto   time                   count
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:56     1
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:57     1
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:58     1
10.3.20.102     HTTP    2017-03-20 17:08:58     1
10.3.20.102     TCP     2017-03-20 17:08:59     3
```

*app.py*

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datetime as dt

disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data', disk_engine)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', tables=[df.to_html()], titles=['ipdst', 'proto'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True)
```

*templates/index.html*

```
<div class=page>
  {% for table in tables %}
    {{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```